# What is the correct way (if any) to use Python 2 and 3 libraries in the same program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I wish to write a python script for that needs to do task 'A' and task 'B'. Luckily there are existing Python modules for both tasks, but unfortunately the library that can do task 'A' is Python 2 only, and the library that can do task 'B' is Python 3 only.

In my case the libraries are small and permissively-licensed enough that I could probably convert them both to Python 3 without much difficulty. But I'm wondering what is the "right" thing to do in this situation - is there some special way in which a module written in Python 2 can be imported directly into a Python 3 program, for example?

Comment: which are the `python3` only libraries?

Comment: @itzmeontv I prefer to keep the question general, since my use case is very specific, but in this case it's some code I found on github for manipulating Japanese text, which of course does all the unicode stuff the Python 3 way.

Answer (score 4):

The "right" way is to translate the Py2-only module to Py3 and offer the translation upstream with a pull request (or equivalent approach for non-git upstream repos).  Seriously.  Horrible hacks to make py2 and py3 packages work together are **not** worth the effort.

Comment: +1, I'm sure this is the right answer - the question was purely about whether there's  way to do it that wouldn't be described as an "ugly hack".

Comment: @Nathaniel, I can't think of any general non-ugly-hack approach.  Always sorry to be a bearer of unwelcome news, but, I call 'em as I see 'em...!

Comment: fully agree with @AlexMartelli' answer. Any mixing of 2 & 3 will result in ugly-hacks, as you can see from my toy example. Such workarounds will not be scalable in any decent sized project.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you know of tools such as [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/2to3.html), that aim to make the job of porting code to py3k easier, just repeating it here for others' reference.

In situations where I have to use libraries from python3 and python2, I've been able to work around it using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) module. Alternatively, I've gotten around this issue with shell scripts that pipes output from the python2 script to the python3 script and vice-versa. This of course covers only a tiny fraction of use cases, but if you're transferring text (or maybe even picklable objects) between 2 & 3, it (or a more thought out variant) should work.

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a *best practice* when it comes to mixing versions of python.

### I present to you an ugly hack

Consider the following simple toy example, involving three files:

```
# py2.py
# file uses python2, here illustrated by the print statement
def hello_world():
    print 'hello world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_world()

# py3.py
# there's nothing py3 about this, but lets assume that there is, 
# and that this is a library that will work only on python3 
def count_words(phrase):
     return len(phrase.split())

# controller.py
# main script that coordinates the work, written in python3
# calls the python2 library through subprocess module
# the limitation here is that every function needed has to have a script 
# associated with it that accepts command line arguments.
import subprocess
import py3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    phrase = subprocess.check_output('python py2.py', shell=True)
    num_words = py3.count_words(phrase)
    print(num_words)

# If I run the following in bash, it outputs `2`
hals-halbook: toy hal$ python3 controller.py 
2
```